# Ajax call taking to failure block for PHP service

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have created a web service using php and when I access from a rest client I get the proper JSON response. I am calling the method from AJAX call integrated in a Drupal site. the service response is HTML hence it is going to error block.

**PHP CODE:**

```js
$api_response = array('result' => 1, 'message' => 'Successfully user added!');
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
 $json_response = json_encode($api_response);
 echo $json_response;
```

**JS CODE:**

```js
$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8888/testService.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("SUCCESS DATA");
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("ERROR OCCURED 123");
        }
      });
```

Comment: try putting `exit;` after the echo. This may sound dumb but give it a try, may be your layout is coming along with the response. Putting exit after echo may stop it.

Comment: I put the exit after the echo statement still same error, actually the response text has the HTML layout

Comment: try separating the html layout from response. check from where the layout is coming and remove it.

Comment: The HTML layout is belonging to the calling function, i.e the php code doesn't have any layout related code. The ajax function is being called from a drupal website.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

The PHP file was present in the same location that of the Drupal instance. Drupal site has a page with name service hence it was returning the HTML template. I moved the service file outside of the Drupal instance and it worked.